# WinForm Application Prevents Machine Restart?

Tags: c#, winforms, restart

I have a WinForm application, and when it's open and I try to restart my computer, my computer just hangs and doesn't restart.  I have to actually close the WinForm app, and then restart, and my computer restarts.

What can I do to solve this?

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!BoolShouldThisClose)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            this.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you manually handling the closing events of the winform application. But even if so I believe the system should have killed the process.

Comment: What is the process/work of the application. I think we can help,  if you can share some more details with us about the app.

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it, I do.  I want to minimize my form to the system tray instead of closing it when the "X" is pressed.  So yeah, not sure how I would work around this when my computer wants to close the application....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to pay attention to the CloseReason so you won't block Windows trying to close your form.  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing) {
            this.Hide();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        else base.OnFormClosing(e);
    }
```

Comment: I have something like this so it must be blocking the close.  How can I get around this?

Comment: I reckon it is not quite something like this.  I cannot guess, post a snippet of your code in your question.

Comment: @Soo: where are you testing the e.CloseReason value in that code?

Comment: CloseReason.UserClosing is only if the user is trying to close the app, not the computer?

Comment: Right, only if the user is closing the window do you want to cancel it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you spawned threads in your app and are they running? If so, make sure they're set to IsBackground = true.